# How to do for-each-group group-adjacent in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Can someone help me convert the below XSLT 2.0 code to XSLT 1.0? Thanks.

<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[E1EDL24]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::E1EDL24)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:sort select="MATNR" order="descending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>        
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:transform>

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Thanks michael, I could not get my head around this muenchian grouping....is it quicker for you to tell me the equivalent code in XSLT 1.0 for the for-each-group code I shared in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try whether the following works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="sort">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="adjacent-group" match="E1EDL24[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::E1EDL24]]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::E1EDL24[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::E1EDL24])][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="E1EDL24[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::E1EDL24])]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=". | key('adjacent-group', generate-id())" mode="sort">
    <xsl:sort select="MATNR" order="descending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="E1EDL24[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::E1EDL24]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Martin, does this code sort everything in the document? I need only E1EDL24 and its sub segments as a group to be sorted. Just not sure about this part? <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="sort">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

Comment: Well, try it, it is meant to sort those adjacent elements.